# Angular 5 <a routerLink> press causes unwanted refresh

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5, angular-routing

When clicking on an anchor tag with a routerLink the router successfully navigates to the route but then refreshes the page. This happens on both Chrome and Edge.

The anchor:

```
<a mat-raised-button color="primary" style="margin-left: 10px;[routerLink]=['/table']">some text</a>
```

routes.module.ts:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: "home", component: HomeComponent },
  { path: "content", component: ImageViewComponent },
  { path: "table", component: TableComponent },
  { path: "", redirectTo: "/home", pathMatch: "full" }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(
      appRoutes,
      { enableTracing: false }
    )
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

app.module.ts:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [

  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    ServerModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FlexLayoutModule,
    MyOwnCustomMaterialModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Angular CLI version used: 1.7.3 
Angular router version: 5.2.8

Comment: Your routerLink is sitting in the inline styling. Possible reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okey i found the problem, it is a problem with the server module

when i removed it my issue resolved

changed:

```
imports: [
  BrowserModule,
  ServerModule,
  AppRoutingModule,
  FlexLayoutModule,
  MyOwnCustomMaterialModule
],
```

to:

```
imports: [
  BrowserModule,
  BrowserAnimationsModule, <-- as a replacment
  AppRoutingModule,
  FlexLayoutModule,
  MyOwnCustomMaterialModule
],
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `style` attribute contained your routerLink attribute because it was enclosed in that attributes value.

```
<a mat-raised-button color="primary" style="margin-left: 10px;[routerLink]=['/table']">some text</a>
```

Should be

```
<a mat-raised-button color="primary" style="margin-left: 10px;" [routerLink]="['/table']">some text</a>
```

Comment: fixed it, it doesnt help unfortunetly

Comment: @uribaum - Maybe there are additional mistakes. For example, your explanation states that the routing occurs and the page is refreshed *after* the route has loaded. Is there something in the destination component or is there also some event code that does something with `window.location` or `href`on an `a` tag?